# What is the meaning of 劃來劃去?

Tags: translation, traditional-characters

In the Story 小蝌蚪找媽媽 there is this sentence i cant understand:
小蝌蚪看見小鴨子跟著媽媽在水裏**劃來劃去**
The tadpole saw the ducklings follow their mama in the water...?
Can someone help? thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a spelling mistake, and should be written as 「划來划去」.

In Traditional Chinese, 「划」 means *to row, to paddle*, e.g. 「划龍舟」 (*to row a dragon boat*). 「劃」 normally means *to delimit, to partition* 「劃分」 or sometimes *to plan* 「計劃」.

> 小蝌蚪看見小鴨子跟著媽媽在水裏划來划去
>
> *The wee tadpoles saw the ducklings following their mother in the water, paddling away.*

---

**References:**

- [萌典](https://www.moedict.tw/%E5%8A%83)
- [國語小字典](http://dict.mini.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/gdic/gsweb.cgi?o=ddictionary)
- [教育部國語辭典簡編本](http://dict.concised.moe.edu.tw/jbdic/index.html)
- [粵語審音配詞字庫](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-can/)

Comment: I'm curious why you said it's a spelling mistake. 劃 is a traditional character for 划.  They should be the same, shouldn't they?

Comment: @dan No, 劃 means something different from 划, they are different characters representing different words. Just like 皇後 is a spelling mistake.

Comment: Ok, I don't know much about the traditional Chinese.  But a quick search in dictionaries suggests it's simply just a variant of 划.

Comment: @dan I don't know what dictionary you checked. Generally, we try to check dictionaries made by language regulatory bodies who regulate the use of Traditional Characters. Since PRC considers Traditional Characters non-standard, any dictionary published in PRC will not correctly describe the **standard use of Traditional Characters** and their corresponding use in word spelling. I've added a few links (3 Taiwan, 1 HK), feel free to check the individual definitions of 劃 and 划 there.

Comment: It seems like in traditional Chinese, it has two characters whilst in simplified Chinese there is only one character 划.

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%88%92#Definitions

划(劃):

1. to row; to paddle

划船  ―  huáchuán  ―  to row a boat